# TensorFlow Keras Softmax layer output has one more dimension respect to the input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, softmax

I have a keras model which end with a Softmax layer.
By definition the output shape of the Softmax is the same of the input, but in my case it has an extra dimension: [1, None, 20] instead of [None, 20]

Can someone explain to me why? for now I fixed with a squeeze but it's still weird

Thank you!

```
 def create_keras_model_embedding():
  l = tf.keras.layers
  a = l.Input(shape=(784,))
  embedded_lookup_feature = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('x', shape=(784))
  dense_features = l.DenseFeatures(embedded_lookup_feature)({'x': a})#{'x': a}
  dense = l.Dense(784)(dense_features)
  dense_2 = l.Dense(10, kernel_initializer='zeros')(dense),
  output = l.Softmax(axis=1)(dense_2)
  output = tf.squeeze(output)
  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=a, outputs=output)
```

Output of model.summary()
[image: summary output]

Comment: Could you flatten before softmax layer? This might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Activation` which is more standard and common practice.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
import tensorflow as tf
def create_keras_model_embedding():
  l = tf.keras.layers
  a = l.Input(shape=(784,))
  embedded_lookup_feature = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('x', shape=(784))
  dense_features = l.DenseFeatures(embedded_lookup_feature)({'x': a})#{'x': a}
  dense = l.Dense(784)(dense_features)
  dense_2 = l.Dense(10, kernel_initializer='zeros')(dense)
  output = l.Activation('softmax')(dense_2)
  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=a, outputs=output)

model = create_keras_model_embedding()
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 784)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_features_2 (DenseFeatu (None, 784)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 784)               615440    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 10)                7850      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 10)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 623,290
Trainable params: 623,290
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________
```

If you want to use softmax, use `axis=-1`.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
import tensorflow as tf
def create_keras_model_embedding():
  l = tf.keras.layers
  a = l.Input(shape=(784,))
  embedded_lookup_feature = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('x', shape=(784))
  dense_features = l.DenseFeatures(embedded_lookup_feature)({'x': a})#{'x': a}
  dense = l.Dense(784)(dense_features)
  dense_2 = l.Dense(10, kernel_initializer='zeros')(dense)
  output = l.Softmax(axis=-1)(dense_2)
  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=a, outputs=output)

model = create_keras_model_embedding()
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)         [(None, 784)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_features_3 (DenseFeatu (None, 784)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 784)               615440    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 10)                7850      
_________________________________________________________________
softmax_1 (Softmax)          (None, 10)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 623,290
Trainable params: 623,290
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Ah thank you, i used Softmax because it is used like this in the official tutorials

Comment: You can use softmax but your axis is wrong, try axis=-1, so that softmax is not applied to None but the last 10 dense units.

Comment: Thank you! Looking at your code i found out that actually the problem was a comma at the end of the row before the softmax!

That comma created a tuple instead of a new layer

Comment: I was gonna say -- in this case, axis=1 and axis=-1 refer to the same axis so it shouldn't make a difference. Also, softmax is supposed to return an output with the same shape as the input, no matter the axis, so adding a dimension would be quite unexpected.

Comment: Actually, in some cases, you have more than 2 dimensions (let's say I want to calculate softmax for LSTM output with temporal dimension), it's necessary to pick up the right axis, by default it's -1 so you don't have to specify but if you use someting like axis=1 you have to be sure it's right.